# content_script only when matches extension uri

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

is it possible to have a content_script that is only injected where the URL matches "chrome-extension://my-extension-id/*"

Im injecting a iframe (the source is local ie chrome-extension://.../dialog.html) in webpages to interact with the user, but i need special permissions, i know it could be done with messages but i'd rather have a content_script injected only in that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to do it, and since nobody answered and googling didn't help I'm answering my own question - i hope this helps someone in the future.

in the injected script i get the extension path by getting its own url

```
var scripts = (document.head||document.documentElement).getElementsByTagName('script');

var self = scripts[scripts.length -1];//get own script element from the DOM

var extensionURL = self.src.match(/^chrome-extension\:\/\/[^\/]+/);
extensionURL = extensionURL && extensionURL[0];
```

extensionURL now is the path to the extension